# Pharo 4 FFI async callbacks

Tags: smalltalk, ffi, pharo

What are the options (if any) to handle asynchronous FFI callbacks in Pharo 4? By asynchronous I mean that callback gets invoked by foreign language library some time after the FFI function that sets the callback has finished and returned to Smalltalk.

Example of NativeBoost callbacks in the image is synchronous (callback happens while the FFI function is executing), will it also work for async callbacks?

Or maybe one of the older FFI mechanisms will be able to handle this situation?

Than there is CogMT which if I understand could handle this case but also much more. Would it be possible to run Pharo 4 with this virtual machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that in Pharo right now :(

The CogMT is experimental and cannot be used for real at the moment, we are working on a ThreadedFFI, which is what you ask for, but it will not be ready until the end of the year (hopefully).

Comment: Are you sure? I think I'm using asynchronous callbacks in LibGit... :) Plain NativeBoost callbacks.

Comment: I'm sure you aren't :) The unique chance that happens is if libgit is using threads by itself (but then we will have a safe issue so I do not think so)

Comment: Well I guess you're right. A callback is always called during the execution of another function (not before or after). And while libgit2 does use threads, they are worker threads, transparent to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

All current effort is in the migration to the Spur VM (and ARM Cog). That is much faster and offers pinned objects (next to 64 bit images). It offers new possibilities that are however not perfectly compatible with the existing machinery. In addition, NativeBoost currently is x86 specific and would need changes for both x64 and ARM.

Comment: So Spur VM and ARM Cog are planned for Pharo 5, but they will provide NativeBoost API compatible FFI? IS there anything in Pharo 4 image that depends on NativeBoost? i.e. can Pharo 4 be used with VM that does not support NativeBoost?

Comment: ARM Cog is a step on the way to ARM Spur. AFAIK there have been some efforts to do cross-architecture NativeBoost style FFI (VirtualCPU). There is an experimental spur image available from the file server